# How to put DataFrame into another dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame with two-level index, and another smaller `DataFrame` with one-level index. I would like to put my smaller dataframe as 3rd-level index of my original DataFrame. Below is my code but it doesnt work

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

index = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([["A", "B"], ["AA", "BB"]])
columns = ["X", "Y"]

df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2],[5,8],[1,2],[5,8]], index = index, columns = columns)


dfSmall = pd.DataFrame([[1,4], [5,6]], index =  ["AAA", "BBB"], columns = columns)


df["3rd level"] = ""
df.set_index("3rd level", append=True, inplace=True)
df.loc[("A", "BB", ["AAA", "BBB"])] = dfSmall # doesnt work
```

Comment: do you want to append the dfsmall dataframe at the end?

Comment: `df.loc[("A", "BB", ["AAA", "BBB"])] = dfSmall` this line describes what I want to do, i.e. I want to add two rows `("A", "BB", "AAA")` and `("A", "BB", "BBB")` whose values are taken from `dfSmall` for appropriate index ("BBB" or "AAA")

Comment: could you post your expected output please

Answer (score 0):

The indexes dont match on two dataframes.

[image: df]

[image: dfSmall]

See that the tuple (A, AA) is different than (AAA). This made df.loc dont work as well.

I suggest you to test df.loc before try to input data with it.